# ANR : Native method - android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce

Tags: android, webview, admob

I am getting ANR in my app. After doing my homework I think it's because of webview as mentioned in the log below.

However still not able to figure what exactly could be root issue.

We are using Google AdMob to show ads.

```
  #01  pc 0x000000000019ee64  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #02  pc 0x00000000003af8c0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::CallStaticIntMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+500)
  #03  pc 0x00000000021d2228  /data/app/~~bZWodQiphatLfvhCA7v2Iw==/com.google.android.webview-PpWdu2cBJsAKmigRGx4V8g==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:339)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:208)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8218)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:626)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1016)
```

Comment: It appears that your stack trace suggests a potential problem with the WebView component, particularly related to Google AdMob. ANRs typically occur when the main thread of an Android application is blocked for too long, Make sure that network requests made by WebView, such as loading ad content from AdMob, are not blocking the main thread, can you share the code where you are loading the Ad, thanks

Comment: Hi @SyedAtifAli, I have checked the code, we are loading the Ad on main thread. Shall we make the request off the main thread, can you please share the reference ?